# How to do a cascade delete in .Netcore 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascading-deletes

In my application, I have this class structure.

```
public class Class1
{
    public long Class1ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Class2> class2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public long Class2ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Link> Link { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Front end:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(long? id)
{
    var r = 1 + 1;
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var Class1 = await _context.Class1.FindAsync(id);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    if (Class1 != null)
    {
        _context.Class1.Remove(Class1);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

The data is data-bound correctly using a local db. I am able to edit and view `Class1` right now. When I try to delete an instance of `Class1` it says I can't because it is being used.

`SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Class2_Class1_Class1ID". The conflict occurred in database "DBName", table "dbo.Class2", column 'Class1ID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

In order to do a cascade delete, do I have to go through the database and delete all the related fields in the `OnPostAsync()` method?  Or is there a much simpler way?

Comment: You cannot delete a class, only an instance of the class.  You can use Dispose() also in some cases.

Comment: Well you didn't show us how you're doing the delete.  Your model code by itself is pretty useless.

Comment: Re: "chain reaction delete":  The term you're looking for is "cascade delete"

Comment: Are these `Entity Framework` classes?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Yes entity framework from a local database I will update my question shortly my apologies.

Comment: After reading @Amy comments, I went to research on "Cascade Delete". I have Added this statement to the relevant DBCOntext : 
 ` modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().HasMany(w => w.Class2).WithOne(t => t.Class1).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`  

After using this statement the error page no shows but the Link data does not get deleted on the cascading effect.